# how to remove subview from view and also release memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Hello I am new in **iOS memory management** my question is when I remove view subview from view that time memory is not decrease. in my I try to make reusable view. There are 3 view is main Display view. When use swap that time all tree view position is change and subview which store in `NSMutableArray`. But when I remove 3 view subview that time it not release memory. my code is in `arc=YES` and My code is Bellow

```
int Position = 0;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];

    // Setting the swipe direction.
    [swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

    // Adding the swipe gesture on image view
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    Position = 0;

    Arr_view = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:View_D1,View_D2,View_D3,View_D4,View_D5,View_D6,View_D7,View_D8,View_D9,View_D10,View_D11,View_D12,View_D13,View_D14 nil];

    [View_D1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    [View_D2 setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 568)];
    [View_D3 setFrame:CGRectMake(640, 0, 320, 568)];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipe {

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)
    {
        Position++;
    }

    if (swipe.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        Position--;
    }
    if (Position>=0 && Position<Arr_view.count)
    {
        [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(ChangePosition) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
    else {
        if (Position<0) {
            Position=0;
        }
        else {
            Position = Arr_view.count-1;
        }
    }
}
-(void)ChangePosition
{
    if (Position%3 == 0) {
        [View_D1 addSubview:(UIView *)[Arr_view objectAtIndex:Position]];

        [View_D1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
        [View_D2 setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 568)];
        [View_D3 setFrame:CGRectMake(640, 0, 320, 568)];

        [[View_D3 subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        [[View_D2 subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

    }
    else if (Position%3 == 1) {
        [View_D2 addSubview:(UIView *)[Arr_view objectAtIndex:Position]];

        [View_D1 setFrame:CGRectMake(640, 0, 320, 568)];
        [View_D2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
        [View_D3 setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 568)];

        [[View_D1 subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        [[View_D3 subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    }
    else  {
        [View_D3 addSubview:(UIView *)[Arr_view objectAtIndex:Position]];

        [View_D1 setFrame:CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 568)];
        [View_D2 setFrame:CGRectMake(640, 0, 320, 568)];
        [View_D3 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];

        [[View_D1 subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
        [[View_D2 subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good only. If you are using arc then no need to worry about releasing of memory. Because in arc you cannot directly control when an object is released,  ARC parses your code and inserts release statements as soon as objects can be released. This frees up the memory for new allocations straight away. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631643/ios-how-to-remove-object-from-memory-with-arc-enabled)

Answer (score 0):

Any NSObject subclass will be deallocated, when it retain count became 0, you have strong reference to you view in you viewController, in this case it enough to remove that view from superview and set reference to it to nil. But if you need to reuse this view, you do not need to deallocate it, and have to leave strong reference to it.